# QGIS Draw by rule

Tags: qgis, symbology, point, rule-based

I have a point layer with several colored dots. Each dot represent a find of a bumblebee species. E.g.

- red is B.terrestris
- yellow is B.hypnorum.

In my attribute table I have a column named "nest" (Boolean).

- When True, a Triangle is drawn
- When False, a dot is drawn

How can I obtain that the color of the triangle is the same as the species' dot?

Answer (score 5):

You can use rule based symbology or data defined override.

Since your case is not too complex, I suggest rule based symbology because you will have a nice legend then.

Set it up the following:

[image]

In case you want to use data defined override you can do it like this for example:

[image]

Use as expression:

```
Case
When "Nest" is true then 'triangle'
When "Nest" is false then 'circle'
end
```

*note the missing legend for dots here.